# Collection#Matching an Association in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I want to use Collection#Matching against associated objects, but it isn't working. Doing some digging it looks like Doctrine does an in_array call against the two values. The needle is a  Persisted Collection (my association) and the haystack is an array of the entities I want to match. Because the needle is a Persisted Collection, the match fails.

Is this possibly a bug or are associations not supported? If they're not supported, is there a work around?

Example:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT c FROM Entity\BidCategory c WHERE c.code IN(:categories)");
$query->setParameter('categories', array('CATEGORY_1', 'CATEGORY_2'));
$my_categories = $query->getResult();

$criteria = array(
"min_pub_date" => "01-07-2012",
"max_pub_date" => "01-08-2012"
);

$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT b From Entity\Bid b JOIN b.categories c WHERE b.pub_date > :min_pub_date AND b.pub_date < :max_pub_date");
$query->setParameter("min_pub_date", new DateTime($criteria['min_pub_date']));
$query->setParameter("max_pub_date", new DateTime($criteria['max_pub_date']));
$query->setMaxResults(1);
$bids = $query->getResult();

$criteria = Criteria::create()
->where(Criteria::expr()->in("categories", $my_categories));

$collection = new Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
foreach($bids as $bid)
{
    $collection->add($bid);
}
$matched_bids = $collection->matching($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Criteria feature doesn't support associations. The `Criteria::expr()->in()` method is for regular arrays.